# VS Code Pylint no member error fix doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pylint

I've entered

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--generated-members"]
```

In VS code settings.json to fix 'Pylint no member error' and now pylint doesn't even work... Did I do something wrong? Is there any other solution?

Comment: I'm not answering the question, just thought I could suggest something -- Microsoft recently came out with "pylance", so you could try that instead. I certainly like it a lot more.

Comment: I tried pylance and It works well, thanks for the suggestion!!

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean to put `--generate-members` instead of `--generated-members`